# PHP session management - Loginmask with MySQL Connection

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

May I am wrong, but i think this codei posted below should work. Any of the PHP-Code won't be executed from line 1 - 10 and 100 - 106. I already tested it on my XAMPP and on my online FTP via a public webhoster. Every other file executed from the FTP or localclient is normally working with PHP (for example the database connection).

And do not wonder the lines 6,7,8 and 100 - 106 are only testlines to see if PHP works properly, which is not the case in my opinion.

Main Goal:
If session is active and the variable 'access' is set then redirect directly to the userview.php.

[Code on pastebin (loginmask)](http://pastebin.com/LJvEKKPZ)

[DB-Connection](http://pastebin.com/hNaS0VhU)

I would be glad if someone could help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What works and what doesn't work? What is your expected output? And finally, what is the output you get?

Comment: The page shows up normally just without the PHP at 1-10 and 100-106 he wont even create the testfiles. Seems like hes ignoring PHP. The javascript post at line 79 works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `<? ?>` tags with `<?php ?>`, or check your `short_open_tag` directive in php.ini file.

Comment: I can't believe the problem was the     <? ?>    tag. I just changed it to <?php ?> and it works fine. Thx